# Web scraping Billboard Hot Airplay chart

Tags: r, authentication, web-scraping

I'm trying to get a hot100 airplay chart from its official website by using R.

```
<http://www.billboard.com/biz/charts/hot-100-airplay>
```

The problem is that I have to somehow log into the website with my id and password. I've tried example codes that Rcurl provided but none of them actually works.

So right now, instead of getting all the chart, I just scraped top four songs for each week. Can anyone offer a solution so I could able to scrape all the info?

Oh and billboard's API is officially closed so I can't expect anything from them. This is what I tried:

```
appannie = getURL("http://www.billboard.com/biz/charts/2013-11-02/hot-100-airplay,   userpwd = tayshin:passward", verbose = TRUE)
```

The output was following:

```
About to connect() to www.billboard.com port 80 (#0)
Trying 93.184.216.229... * connected
Connected to www.billboard.com (93.184.216.229) port 80 (#0)
GET /biz/charts/2013-11-02/hot-100-airplay, userpwd = tayshin:passward HTTP/1.1
Host: www.billboard.com
Accept: */*

HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Date: Sun, 03 Nov 2013 06:52:23 GMT
Server: ECSF (sjc/4F95)

Closing connection #0

appannie
[1] ""
```

Also, this one doesn't work.

```
 x = getURL("http://www.billboard.com/biz/charts/2013-11-02/hot-100-airplay",  userpwd = "tayshin:password")
```

It outputs something but the infos are limited.

Comment: Please provide code for what you've tried so far.

Comment: I've edited! thanks for telling me that